# Countif working with Excel to count only the first name in the list

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I would like to use this formula to check column A with below names:

`SUM(COUNTIFS([Consolidate.xls]RawData!$A:$A,{"*Kobe Bryant*","*John Legend*","*Tom Kitten*","*Jason Kidd*","*Michael Jordan*"}))`

Consolidate.xls, Row A:

```
     A
1  Kobe Bryant; Tom Kitten
2  Michael Jordan
```

As the result I will get 3. How can I ignore Tom Kitten in row 1?
(I just need the first person to be counted and let me get the result =2.)

Comment: I guess you know, how the asterisk work? It's a **wildchard character** meaning it can be anything before and after the word. So if you could get rid of them, that would be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by removing the wildcard (`*`) before each name. That way, the name will only be counted if it appears at the beginning of the cell value.

`SUM(COUNTIFS([Consolidate.xls]RawData!$A:$A,{"Kobe Bryant*","John Legend*","Tom Kitten*","Jason Kidd*","Michael Jordan*"}))`

The above equation would give the desired result, based on your data:

> 2